# Selecting Max from a nullable int field with LINQ

Tags: mysql, linq, int, nullable

I am trying to find the biggest ordernumber(int?) in a MYSQL database with LINQ:

```
 int maxOrdernumber = context.DataContext.Purchaseorders.Where(r=> (r.Ordernumber.HasValue)).Max(r=>r.Ordernumber);
```

but it says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. Are you missing a cast?

In my understanding, the first part of the expression filters the field only to those, which has value.

Comment: I think your linq expression returns nullable int. And you are trying to set it into integer. If i were you, i would try to set the linq expression result into a nullable int. (int? maxOrdernumber). Because your linq expression may returns null. (in case the database cannot contains a row that provide the conditions.)

Comment: This is not a good solution, since the reason I want the highest order number is because this expression is part of a new order saving process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, this should do it:

```
int maxOrdernumber = context.DataContext.Purchaseorders.Where(r=> (r.Ordernumber.HasValue)).Max(r=>r.Ordernumber.Value);
```

Comment: Note this will fail if there are no non-null values: `Max` fails on a collection of zero elements.

Comment: I believe that's acceptable, test for `Any()` if this is an issue beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `Where` will be `IEnumerable<int>>`. Thus the result of the `Max` will be a `int?`.

But you are assigning to an `int` and you cannot assign a nullable of-T to  a T without doing something.

Normally the null-coalescing operator is used:

```
int res = some-expression-that-is-nullable ?? some-default;
```

Or you could assign to a `int?`and deal with the null case elsewhere. If you know there will always be at least one non-null value found the null-coalescing option is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'

Yes, this is due to Nullable field.
Place a .value after r.OrderNumber will resolve your problem !
The only problem of .value is when it's empty but you already checked it.

So here is your code :

```
int maxOrdernumber = context.DataContext.Purchaseorders.Where(r=> (r.Ordernumber.HasValue)).Max(r=>r.Ordernumber.Value);
```